# calling a parent controller function in EXTjs from an Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, extjs

Good day all, I'm struck on this easy problem, I need your advice once more:

I'm editing a EXTjs application (which I didn't do).
in this application, there is at some point an iframe, that call an external html file, defined:

```
items: [{
        xtype: "component",
        id: "dasboardM",
        autoEl: {
            tag: "iframe",
            width: '100%',
            height: '95%',
            src: "/resources/extendpanel/dashboard.html"
        }
    }]
```

I need to call functions defined in the view controller FROM the iframe, there will be several function to be called, and for now I've setted up a simple test case, so I've created the controller for the view file that has the iframe like the following:

```
Ext.define('Dor3.view.merch.MerchController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.merch',
    ...
    onIframeCall : function(){
    console.log("fromIframe!");
    }
```

well, in the iframe I have this code, which I have found on the sencha forums, an old thread:

```
$(".iframeToExt").click(function(){
    var myParent = window.parent;
    var controller = myParent.window.Dor3.app.getController('Dor3.view.merch.MerchController');
    controller.onIframeCall();
    });
```

this is actually not working, well, is there a way to call that function from the iframe?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but have you tried removing window from the iFrame call?
myParent.Dor3.app.getController

Comment: strange, now I get this new error:
Application.js?_dc=20161104143508:516 Uncaught TypeError: controller.doInit is not a function

which is nice, because Ext is answering... but... what is doInit? do I have to define it?

Answer (score 2):

You can send a message from an `iframe` to the parent window and write code that responds to it. For example from an `iframe` execute:

```
window.parent.postMessage('message', '*');
```

And in the `MerchController` you can implement `onmessage` like this:

```
window.onmessage = function(ev){
    if (ev.data == 'message') {
        controller.onIframeCall();
    }
};
```

Note that instead of `'message'` you can pass an object if you need to. Check API info for [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use (appname).app.getController(controller's full name)
This will return you controller object & you can call that controller's method.